# How to obtain multiple rows in one query?

Tags: mysql

I have a small table in MySQL as follows:

```
 pid   pName    pPrice
  1    TBall    100.00
  2    MBall    200.00
  3    TJers    250.00
  4    MJers    275.00
```

I want to obtain multiple row as a result in a single query:

```
Select * from <tablename> where pName='Tball' and 'MBall';
```

(This code is wrong; I want an correct solution that is similiar to this.)

The query should yield the following result:

```
pid  pName  pPrice
 1   TBall  100.00
 2   MBall  200.00
```

Comment: `... WHERE pName = 'Tball' OR pName = 'MBall';`

Comment: Good @aioobe, well done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question would be:

- Q. "What did I do to avoid getting all the rows?"
- A. You added a constraining `WHERE` clause
- Q. "How do I make it ***les*** restrictive?"
- A. Make the constraint less restrictive.
- Q. "Do you have some examples of how I can do that?"
- A. Well yes. There's an *expression syntax* for the where clause. Among
  others there are the *logical operators* (`AND`, `OR`, `NOT`), you can check
  equality (=, `IS NULL`). Many dialects of SQL have additional operators
  (`BETWEEN`, `LIKE`) and lastly all should have the `IN` operator.

All operators can be combined, and sub expressions can be enclosed within
parentheses like you would to distinguish `3 * (7 + 5)` from `(3 * 7) + 5`.

Here you could simply use the `OR` logical operator:

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE (pName = 'TBall') OR (pName = 'MBall');
```

Or, you can use `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE pName IN ('TBall','MBall');
```

Or, you can use even `LIKE` for your use case:

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE pName LIKE '%Ball';
```